# Actionscript: How to obtain stage property in added children?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I am trying to trace stage.name in child view after addChild:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextField;
public class TestView extends TextField {
    public function TestView() {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, handleAddedToStage);
    }

    private function handleAddedToStage(event : Event) : void {
        this.text = "TEXT ON TEXTFIELD";
        trace("Stage is"+stage.name);
        trace("Stage width"+stage.stageWidth);
    }
}
```

stage.name is already overrided: in Main:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
public class Main extends Sprite {
    public function Main() {
        addChild(new TestView());
    }
    override public  function get name():String {
        return "MAINSTAGE";
    }
}
```

But getting null in log:
tail: flashlog.txt: file truncated
Stage isnull

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why the `stage` returns `null`, but overriding `name` in the `Main` class won't effect the `stage.name` property. The `stage` variable of a display object points to the globally unique `Stage` object of the flash movie which is different from the `Main` instance. In AS3 there is a unique `flash.display.Stage` instance which is accessible from any display object that is currently on the display list (added using `addChild` methods). If you want to access your main `Sprite` instance, use `displayObject.root` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can access stage from anywhere inside your flex application with **Application.application.stage**

Answer (score 0):

Not quite clear on what you're trying to accomplish, but from a quick test I ran, `stage` is not null, but `stage.name` *is* null.  I'm using Flex.  That's probably just because we haven't given it a name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <s:Button id="button"
        addedToStage="trace(button.stage);trace(button.stage.name)"
        click="trace(button.stage.name)"
        horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"/>

</s:Application>
```

Output:

```
[object Stage]
null
null
```

Overriding `get name` in Main won't affect this.